# github pages won't host my react webpack project

Tags: git, github, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I already had my project on master branch of remote repo so I just made a new branch on terminal with "git checkout -b gh-pages" and then pushed it with "git push origin gh-pages".

I then went to my site (http://jacky-lei.github.io/DatePicker/ but it didn't load. My project is using react, jQuery, and webpack, and Babel. Is there other stuff I should have done to make it work? Here is my github repo: https://github.com/Jacky-Lei/DatePicker/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Github link redirects me to `http://jackylei.space/DatePicker/` and I can see calendar.

Comment: For some reason, it wasn't working earlier, but I guess I have to wait 10 minutes? Thanks again @BobSponge

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: [Deploying a React Webpack app (not created with create-react-app) to Github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545439/deploying-a-react-webpack-app-not-created-with-create-react-app-to-github-page)

It looks like one answer is to make webpack deploy to the root directory (/) rather than (/dist).