# Deploying a React Webpack app (not created with create-react-app) to Github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, react-router, github-pages

I'm fairly new to the React ecosystem; I've made a simple single page webpage for a tech conference and I want to deploy it to gh-pages.

I know create-react-app has [very good documentation](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) on deploying to gh-pages but my app was not made with that. I manually setup all the configurations for Webpack and React, instead of using the react-scripts module that create-react-app uses.

I tried finding some posts about deploying a non-create-react-app to gh-pages but I've had no luck so I was wondering if there's any simple solutions.

My current solution is to just push only the dist folder to the gh-pages and serve that. I wanted to see if there's a simpler way where I can just push the whole dev branch over to gh-pages and be able to serve the correct elements still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push the whole dev branch and select github to display the page from `master` branch. Make sure that in `master` branch the scripts are compiled into `/` (index) of the repository, so your page shows up.

Comment: Are you saying to avoid compiling it into a dist/ folder and just compiling everything to the root dir?

Comment: That's exactly what Im saying

Comment: I'm currently having this same issue and I know this was a while ago, but how would I do this, pushing the whole dev branch and making sure the scripts are compiled correctly

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late on this question, but you can use `gulp` with `gulp-gh-pages` to automate pushing a React build to Github Pages.